# How to get value of a tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get data-id value from a tag in the jquery from the edit button.

HTML:
It's a table.

```
            $html .= '<tbody>';
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$row['designation'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>';
            $html .= '<a data-id="'.$row['id'].'"  href="#" id="edit"  class=" icon btn btn-info btn-sm mr-1">Edit</a>';
            $html .= '<a href="#" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
            $html .= '</td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';
            $html .= '</tbody>';
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.table').on('click',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
       var anchor =$(event.target).children('#edit');
       var id=anchor.attr('data-id');
       console.log(id);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#edit').on('click',function () {
   var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
   console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>designation</td>
<td>
<a data-id="5"  href="#" id="edit"  class=" icon btn btn-info btn-sm mr-1">Edit</a>
<a href="#" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Try this code:-

```
$('#edit').on('click',function () {
   var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
   console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: On click is only working on table. I tried <td> , <a>. It does nothing

Comment: Yeah it works. But i think there is some other problem in my code. That's why t's not working.

Comment: so marked it as true so other can use it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code..

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <td data-id="abc">1</td>
    <td data-id="def">1</td>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('td').each(function() {
        $('body').on('click','td',function() {
             var text = $(this).attr("data-id");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: On click is only working on table. I tried `<td>` , `<a>`. It does nothing